# Difference between burst and request per second in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I read nginx article in this site (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) and I have 4 request per second in my site and I want to use limit_req_zone for preventing DDOS attack.

I can not figure out what is the difference between

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=flood:10m rate=4r/s; 
limit_req zone=flood burst=0;
```

which allows 4 requests per second and

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=flood:10m rate=1r/s; 
limit_req zone=flood burst=4 nodelay;
```

which also allows 4 requests per second?

that the second configuration works in my site and the first one does not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure `rate=4r/s` it means the server will process one request every 250 ms and return code 503 for requests faster than this rate.

When you configure a `burst=4`, the server will queue 4 requests, so it will accept 4 requests at once, but it will forward them at the `1r/s` rate. So it will return code 503 only to the 5th request within the rate limit.

The `nodelay` option will forward the 4 requests at once, but the server will keep their queue slot as if it is busy until the rate limit is satisfied.

A site may perform more than one request at once to get more than one info, so it can build and load the whole page content. It depends on the application, but it is probably the reason the load fails. Since  after the page is built, a few seconds will pass until the user do something, the `burst` configuration works. It allows several requests at once for loading the page and some time will pass until the next user interaction, so the server has time to free the queue buffer.

More details in this [nginx blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/)